# Word count in CKEditor 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, ckeditor, word-count

I'm using the [Word count Plugin](http://w8tcha.github.io/CKEditor-WordCount-Plugin/) on CKEditor 4, but it exceeds the character count every time.

Here is my config:

```
config.wordcount = {

// Whether or not you want to show the Char Count
showCharCount: true,

// Option to limit the characters in the Editor, for example 200 in this case.
charLimit: 200
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give an example of text that "exceeds" the word count

Comment: "Sometimes" is not the most precise description of the problem. And if this happens sometimes, then maybe you should report a bug to the plugin author?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I set the char limit to 10 and just typed "xdfxcfgcdcggvg"

Comment: @Reinmar It happens every time ;)

Comment: @HariSankar - Please edit your question and add that info. Also, change sometimes to every time, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Basically, I need to restrict users to enter not more than 2000 chars.

Answer (score 3):

The WordCount plugin only counts words - it doesn't prevent you from entering text.

I wrote a similar plugin a while ago (http://ckeditor.com/comment/128388#comment-128388) which counted words or characters and allowed you to enter a "warning" limit which got displayed at the bottom.

The difficultly of limiting to a specific number of characters in CKE is that markup counts as content.  It's a doddle to do with a regular textarea, but once you start using having bold and anchor tags involved it's much more complicated - does your character limit include or exclude markup?  If it includes then how do you want to handle closing tags?  If you want to limit to words then it's a little easier, but still not a walk in the park.  Of course then you have to factor in pasting too ;)

Personally if I were tackling this, I'd hook into the counter so that if you exceed the count (this excludes all markup) you disable the ability to save.

Answer (score 1):

You need a comma after `charLimit: 200`:

```
charLimit: 200,
```

you also need:

```
config.extraPlugins = "wordcount,notification";
```

Comment: I think its `maxCharCount:200`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set maxCharCount: 200, hardlimit: true

```
maxCharCount: 200,
hardlimit: true,
```

Please find below the config

```
config.extraPlugins = 'wordcount';

    config.wordcount = {
            
            showCharCount: true,
            
            maxCharCount: 200,

            hardLimit: true,

    };
```

for more details refer to [Word Count Plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/wordcount#:%7E:text=editorConfig%20%3D%20function(%20config%20)%20%7B,of%20Words%20in%20your%20CKEditor.)